# Converting GeoJSON data into proper Array

Tags: jquery

I want to convert data from geoJSON to an array. It's a bit tricky but I got my way until I got stuck here:

```
  // Get data in open
  var dataInput = e.features[0].properties.open;

  // Remove { and } and " "
  var removeLetter = dataInput.replace('{', '');
  var removeLetter1 = removeLetter.replace('}', '');
  var removeLetter2 = removeLetter1.replace(/"/g, '');
  var dataString = removeLetter2.match(/[^,]+,[^,]+/g);

  // Loop 
  dataString.forEach(function(item) {
     console.log(item);
  });
```

This is my result: 
[image]

But it should look like this:

```
       var data = {
            monday: [[8.30, 18.30]],
            tuesday: [[8.30, 18.30]],
            wednesday: [[6.30, 18.30]],
            thursday: [[6.30, 18.30]],
            friday: [[6.30, 18.30]],
            saturday: [[6.30, 18.30]],
            sunday: [[6.30, 18.30]],
        };
```

Comment: I have almost zero js experience but does not the fact that you're using [`forEach`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp) imply that your entries are already in an array?  and that `console.log(dataString)` would give you a print similar to your desired output?

Comment: To clarify, what exactly is your question/problem? It's unclear, are you having problems with creating an output array or are your regular expressions giving poor results? I would add a print before your loop where you log `dataString`. Is the problem  maybe that your desired output is, for example,  `8.30` instead of the output `8`? Maybe don't manipulate the strings using regular expressions but instead parse them first with JSON and then use object.keys? raw string regexing is risky reguardless of the language.